# Brackets AEM extension timeout

Tags: synchronization, localhost, frontend, aem, brackets

I installed AEM extension to synchronize my repository with local instance of AEM, and it doesn't work, when I try to sync I have "timeout" response in console probably filter.xml is wrong but I don't know how to fix this.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workspaceFilter version="1.0">
    <filter root="etc/designs/zg/internship-project" mode="replace"/>
</workspaceFilter>`

[That's my settings in extension options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWHMx.png)

[That's my project structure I want to synchronize everything in internship-project folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7XWP.png)

Comment: I don't use brackets, I'm more of an IntelliJ + IntelliVault perosn, but if the request times out, there may be a problem with your instance. Is it up and running? Is it using the port `4502`? Are all the bundles active?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy by any chance?

Comment: The recommended IDE's for AEM are Eclipse and IntelliJ. I personally use IntelliJ with the AEM IDE Tooling plugin for seamless integration.

Answer (score 0):

Try to refresh file tree from left navigation and retry. If that is not working, try to close and reopen brackets

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).